# A stored procedure returns multiple values but only need one

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I'm trying to build a stored procedure that seems to return a grid. But I only need the first column of that grid. Below is the code I'm using to call the procedure

```
USE [OperationsView]

DECLARE @ProductionDate  As DateTime
DECLARE @tag_in As VARCHAR(80)
DECLARE @FCChemGALPERMIN float
DECLARE @pi_server As VARCHAR(32)
DECLARE @endDate As DateTime
DECLARE @Debug As Bit
DECLARE @result As Float

SELECT @ProductionDate = '2016-12-01 07:00:00'
SELECT @tag_in = 'I-FC-835'
SELECT @pi_server = 'valpi'
SELECT @endDate = DATEADD(DAY, 1, @productionDate)
SELECT @Debug = 1

EXEC @FCChemGALPERMIN = Interface.proc_GetPIValueAverageTime 
           @result, @tag_in, @ProductionDate, @endDate, @pi_server, @Debug 
 PRINT @FCChemGALPERMIN   
 PRINT 'done'
```

Under the results tab I need that float value, I don't care about the percentage next to it. Below this picture is what I get from the messages tab. Basically I want to grab that float value and assign it to a variable so I can display it in the messages tab also.

Results tab looks like this:
[image: Results]

Messages tab looks like this:
[image: message tab]

The ChemGALPERMIN displays 0 when I simply  print that variable. What do I do to get desired float number?

Comment: Why can't you and your code just ignore the second column? Your application doesn't **have** to display everything it receives. If you're only talking about SSMS, ???

Comment: my code and i have tried that but havent had much luck

Comment: @Gio I think your problem is not in the number of columns returned but in the WAY you return the result from sproc. See my answer below.

Comment: Without seeing the code of the stored procedure, it's hard to help you. It looks like you are trying to use the return value of the stored procedure to output, but [that's not what that's for](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-using-select-or-return-instead-of-output), and you can't return a float with a return value anyway. Try using an output parameter (again, we could show you how to do that, but we kind of need to see how the code looks now to tell you how to change it).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considering there is a need for second column some where else.

Insert the result into temp table and take the float value from there

```
Insert into #temp(float_col,percent_col)
EXEC Interface.Proc_getpivalueaveragetime
  @result,
  @tag_in,
  @ProductionDate,
  @endDate,
  @pi_server,
  @Debug 

select @FCChemGALPERMIN= float_col
From #temp
```

If your second column is not useful at any case then alter your procedure from resulting percentage column

Comment: i dont need the second column. i just cant get the first float value into a variable

Answer (score 1):

If `Interface.Proc_getpivalueaveragetime` is a stored procedure and NOT a user defined function, then **you CANNOT return a value from stored procedure like that**.

**UPDATE:** if you are sure that your stored procedure will ALWAYS return only 1 float value and the stored procedure doesn't update physical tables data, then you can convert it to a user defined function ([CREATE FUNCTION](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186755.aspx#Anchor_10) examples) then you will be able to use it the way you have it in your original post, i.e. @result = Interface.Proc_GetPIvalueAverageTime(...) .

But if you still want to keep it as a stored procedure call then you need to pass an additional parameter to `Interface.Proc_GetPIValueAverageTime` and mark it as OUTPUT. Then in the body of your stored procedure, probably in the end of it when you already have the needed float value, you need to set that additional OUTPUT param to the calculated float value.

So, in code it will look something like this (you need to update your stored procedure definition):

```
CREATE PROCEDURE Interface.proc_GetPIValueAverageTime 
           @result float, 
           @tag_in varchar(80), 
           @ProductionDate DATETIME, 
           @endDate DATETIME, 
           @pi_server VARCHAR(32),
           @Debug bit,
           -- new param below
           @sproc_result float OUTPUT
AS
BEGIN
... do your calc ..
set @sproc_result = @calculation_result_as_float
END
```

Then in the calling context you need to define that extra result var (or use the one you already have called @result ) and pass that extra param to the stored procedure call:

```
declare @sproc_result float;

EXEC @FCChemGALPERMIN = Interface.proc_GetPIValueAverageTime 
           @result, @tag_in, @ProductionDate, @endDate, @pi_server, @Debug,
           @sproc_result OUTPUT

-- here @sproc_result will have the float value you've assigned to it in the stored procedure body.
print cast(@sproc_result as varchar(15))
```

Note, IIRC you need to specify **OUTPUT** after the returning param **both in the stored procedure definition and in the calling statement**.

Note, you're already passing the @result var as the first param into your stored procedure. then just add `OUTPUT` modifier to it both in the stored procedure definition and calling statement and assign the value to it in the stored procedure body. This way you won't need the new stored procedure param which I've named `@sproc_result`.

HTH